# How to fill missing dates by groups in a table in sql

Tags: sql, date, loops

I want to know how to use loops to fill in missing dates with value zero based on the start/end dates by groups in sql so that i have consecutive time series in each group. I have two questions.

1. how to loop for each group?
2. How to use start/end dates for each group to dynamically fill in missing dates?

My input and expected output are listed as below.

**Input:** I have a table A like

```
date     value      grp_no
8/06/12    1         1
8/08/12    1         1
8/09/12    0         1
8/07/12    2         2
8/08/12    1         2
8/12/12    3         2
```

Also I have a table B which can be used to left join with A to fill in missing dates.

```
date
...
8/05/12
8/06/12
8/07/12
8/08/12
8/09/12
8/10/12
8/11/12
8/12/12
8/13/12
...
```

How can I use A and B to generate the following output in sql?

**Output:**

```
date     value      grp_no
8/06/12    1         1  
8/07/12    0         1
8/08/12    1         1
8/09/12    0         1
8/07/12    2         2
8/08/12    1         2
8/09/12    0         2
8/10/12    0         2
8/11/12    0         2
8/12/12    3         2
```

Please send me your code and suggestion. Thank you so much in advance!!!

Comment: what are columns in B?

Comment: It only has a date column - all consecutive dates in year 2012.

Comment: What database system and version you're using?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can do it like this without loops

```
SELECT p.date, COALESCE(a.value, 0) value, p.grp_no
  FROM
(
  SELECT grp_no, date
    FROM
  (
    SELECT grp_no, MIN(date) min_date, MAX(date) max_date
      FROM tableA
     GROUP BY grp_no
  ) q CROSS JOIN tableb b 
   WHERE b.date BETWEEN q.min_date AND q.max_date
) p LEFT JOIN TableA a
    ON p.grp_no = a.grp_no 
   AND p.date = a.date
```

*The innermost subquery grabs min and max dates per group. Then cross join with `TableB` produces all possible dates within the min-max range per group. And finally outer select uses outer join with `TableA` and fills `value` column with `0` for dates that are missing in `TableA`.*

Output:

```
|       DATE | VALUE | GRP_NO |
|------------|-------|--------|
| 2012-08-06 |     1 |      1 |
| 2012-08-07 |     0 |      1 |
| 2012-08-08 |     1 |      1 |
| 2012-08-09 |     0 |      1 |
| 2012-08-07 |     2 |      2 |
| 2012-08-08 |     1 |      2 |
| 2012-08-09 |     0 |      2 |
| 2012-08-10 |     0 |      2 |
| 2012-08-11 |     0 |      2 |
| 2012-08-12 |     3 |      2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4bab/6)** demo

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try out today and let you know if it works!

Comment: @peterm +1 for showing a non-trivial example of using time dimensions... Haven't found many gems like this yet (not sure if I've found any using group by)

Comment: this is great !

Answer (score 3):

The following query does a `union` with `tableA` and `tableB`.  It then uses group by to merge the rows from `tableA` and `tableB` so that all of the dates from `tableB` are in the result.  If a date is not in `tableA`, then the row has 0 for `value` and `grp_no`.  Otherwise, the row has the actual values for `value` and `grp_no`.

```
select
   dat,
   sum(val),
   sum(grp)
from
   (
      select
         date as dat,
         value as val,
         grp_no as grp
      from
         tableA
   union
      select
         date,
         0,
         0
      from
         tableB
      where
         date >= date '2012-08-06' and
         date <= date '2012-08-13'
   )
group by
   dat
order by
   dat
```

I find this query to be easier for me to understand.  It also runs faster.  It takes 16 seconds whereas a similar `right join` query takes 32 seconds.

This solution only works with numerical data.

This solution assumes a fixed date range.  With some extra work this query can be adapted to limit the date range to what is found in `tableA`.

Comment: I have looked every where for something this simple.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

I just needed the query to return all the dates in the period I wanted.  Without the joins.   Thought I'd share for those wanting to put them in your query.  Just change the 365 to whatever timeframe you are wanting.

```
DECLARE @s DATE = GETDATE()-365, @e DATE = GETDATE();
SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @s, @e)+1)
 DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number)-1, @s)
 FROM [master].dbo.spt_values
 WHERE [type] = N'P' ORDER BY number
```