# Adding in missing dates from results in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database that currently looks like this

```
Date     | valid_entry | profile
1/6/2015   1           | 1
3/6/2015   2           | 1
3/6/2015   2           | 2
5/6/2015   4           | 4
```

I am trying to grab the dates but i need to make a query to display also for dates that does not exist in the list, such as 2/6/2015.

This is a sample of what i need it to be:

```
Date     | valid_entry
1/6/2015   1
2/6/2015   0
3/6/2015   2
3/6/2015   2
4/6/2015   0
5/6/2015   4
```

My query:

```
select date, count(valid_entry)
from database
where profile = 1
group by 1;
```

This query will only display the dates that exist in there. Is there a way in query that I can populate the results with dates that does not exist in there?

Comment: Please refer following links [Insert Missing Dates from a query](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75473/insert-missing-dates-from-a-query) [How to fill missing dates by groups in a table in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075098/how-to-fill-missing-dates-by-groups-in-a-table-in-sql)

Comment: Can you use a dummy table where you have all the dates, and then use union to get the -not in the actual table- dates?

Comment: I don't understand how you calculate the values for `valid_entry` in the expected output. Where does the `4` com from on the second line? Shouldn't that be `0` as there is no row for 2015-06-02?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry, it should be 0. I updated the code as followed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate a list of all dates that are between the start and end date from your source table using `generate_series()`. These dates can then be used in an outer join to sum the values for all dates.

```
with all_dates (date) as (
  select dt::date
  from generate_series( (select min(date) from some_table), (select max(date) from some_table), interval '1' day) as x(dt)
)
select ad.date, sum(coalesce(st.valid_entry,0))
from all_dates ad
  left join some_table st on ad.date = st.date
group by ad.date, st.profile
order by ad.date;
```

`some_table` is your table with the sample data you have provided.

Based on your sample output, you also seem to want group by `date` **and** `profile`, otherwise there can't be two rows with 2015-06-03. You also don't seem to want `where profile = 1` because that as well wouldn't generate two rows with 2015-06-03 as shown in your sample output.

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b0b2a/2

---

<sup>Unrelated, but: I hope that the column names are only made up. `date` is a **horrible** name for a column. For one because it is also a keyword, but more importantly it does not *document* what this date is for. A start date? An end date? A due date? A modification date?</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much. This is very close to what i needed. Yeah the columns are made up. The actual database is much bigger than this but these are the 3 columns that I am focusing on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a calendar table for this purpose. In this case you can create an in-line table with the tables required, then `LEFT JOIN` your table to it:

```
select "date", count(valid_entry)
from (
   SELECT '2015-06-01' AS d UNION ALL '2015-06-02' UNION ALL '2015-06-03' UNION ALL
          '2015-06-04' UNION ALL '2015-06-05' UNION ALL '2015-06-06') AS t
left join database AS db on t.d = db."date" and db.profile = 1
group by t.d;
```

**Note:** Predicate `profile = 1` should be applied in the `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN` operation. If it is placed in the `WHERE` clause instead then `LEFT JOIN` essentially becomes an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I thought it was a mysql question!

Comment: Sadly, This is not what i am looking for as this is a little too static for what I need it for.