# View does not expand records

Tags: sql, view, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using a cross join approach I discovered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075098/how-to-fill-missing-dates-by-groups-in-a-table-in-sql), I fill the data gaps with a date dimension when  my subscribers (below shown as "site id") have no activity.

This SELECT statement works flawlessly:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN SITE_ID IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(SITE_ID) OVER (
        ORDER BY EVENT_DATE ) 
        ELSE SITE_ID
    END AS SITE_ID,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNTRY_NAME IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(COUNTRY_NAME) OVER (
        ORDER BY EVENT_DATE ) 
        ELSE COUNTRY_NAME
    END AS COUNTRY_NAME,
    CASE
        WHEN PRODUCT_NAME IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(PRODUCT_NAME) OVER (
        ORDER BY EVENT_DATE ) 
        ELSE PRODUCT_NAME
    END AS PRODUCT_NAME,
    EVENT_DATE,
    COALESCE(ACTIVE_SUBSCRIPTIONS, 0) AS ACTIVE_SUBSCRIPTIONS,
    CASE
        WHEN ACTIVE_SUBSCRIPTIONS_CUMUL IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(ACTIVE_SUBSCRIPTIONS_CUMUL) OVER (
        ORDER BY EVENT_DATE ) 
        ELSE ACTIVE_SUBSCRIPTIONS_CUMUL
    END AS ACTIVE_SUBSCRIPTIONS_CUMUL,
...

FROM 
(
    SELECT
        A.SITE_ID,
        A.COUNTRY_NAME,
        A.PRODUCT_NAME,
        P.DATE_KEY AS EVENT_DATE,
        A.ACTIVE_SUBSCRIPTIONS,
        A.ACTIVE_SUBSCRIPTIONS_CUMUL,
...
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            SITE_ID,
            DATE_KEY
        FROM
            (
            SELECT
                SITE_ID,
                MIN(EVENT_DATE) MIN_DATE,
                MAX(EVENT_DATE) MAX_DATE
            FROM
                SUBSCRIPTION
            GROUP BY
                SITE_ID
) Q
        CROSS JOIN  DIM_DATE B
        WHERE
            B.DATE_KEY BETWEEN Q.MIN_DATE AND Q.MAX_DATE
) P
    LEFT JOIN SUBSCRIPTION_BREAKDOWN A
ON
        P.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID
        AND P.DATE_KEY = A.EVENT_DATE
) t ORDER BY EVENT_DATE
```

I just put a WHERE clause in the innermost query for a SITE and I get data for days of activity and days without activity, like this

[image]

Here 1/10/22 is the day without activity.

For ease of use, I created a view based on this code. When I run a query against it

```
select * from subscription_by_site_vw where site_id = 'XhY8La7GTfs'
```

I only get data for days of activity, like this
[image]

Here, the day without activity (1/10/22) does not show.

I created a table with the same code and I have the same issue. I am on Snowflake but I created this fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=35cba993cf03d442a0831b71c864123b) using Postgres and the view works correctly.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Its most likely predicate pushing - you predicate from view gets pushed inside and is only selecting rows satisfying condition for site-it, which I believe does not includes day without activity and later applies other condition clauses.

Comment: @Pankaj Bingo. This was the problem. I found Oracle doc that explains the behavior quite well here https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/tuning/ctuntransform22576.html#ctuntransform22576

I removed the `ORDER BY EVENT_DATE` statement and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Good, would be helpful for others if you can post solution too that you used for this, as this is a very common problem, hence more solutions can help someone dig into their issues.

Comment: Ok, I'll answer my question and post my code with the solution. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was caused by predicate pushing. I found an article in the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/tuning/ctuntransform22576.html#ctuntransform22576) that lists the limitations. The last line of my code had an ORDER BY statement which should never have been there (see doc). This is my code fix (scroll to the end):

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN SITE_ID IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(SITE_ID) OVER (
        ORDER BY EVENT_DATE ) 
        ELSE SITE_ID
    END AS SITE_ID,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNTRY_NAME IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(COUNTRY_NAME) OVER (
        ORDER BY EVENT_DATE ) 
        ELSE COUNTRY_NAME
    END AS COUNTRY_NAME,
    CASE
        WHEN PRODUCT_NAME IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(PRODUCT_NAME) OVER (
        ORDER BY EVENT_DATE ) 
        ELSE PRODUCT_NAME
    END AS PRODUCT_NAME,
    EVENT_DATE,
    COALESCE(ACTIVE_SUBSCRIPTIONS, 0) AS ACTIVE_SUBSCRIPTIONS,
    CASE
        WHEN ACTIVE_SUBSCRIPTIONS_CUMUL IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(ACTIVE_SUBSCRIPTIONS_CUMUL) OVER (
        ORDER BY EVENT_DATE ) 
        ELSE ACTIVE_SUBSCRIPTIONS_CUMUL
    END AS ACTIVE_SUBSCRIPTIONS_CUMUL,
...

FROM 
(
    SELECT
        A.SITE_ID,
        A.COUNTRY_NAME,
        A.PRODUCT_NAME,
        P.DATE_KEY AS EVENT_DATE,
        A.ACTIVE_SUBSCRIPTIONS,
        A.ACTIVE_SUBSCRIPTIONS_CUMUL,
...
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            SITE_ID,
            DATE_KEY
        FROM
            (
            SELECT
                SITE_ID,
                MIN(EVENT_DATE) MIN_DATE,
                MAX(EVENT_DATE) MAX_DATE
            FROM
                SUBSCRIPTION
            GROUP BY
                SITE_ID
) Q
        CROSS JOIN  DIM_DATE B
        WHERE
            B.DATE_KEY BETWEEN Q.MIN_DATE AND Q.MAX_DATE
) P
    LEFT JOIN SUBSCRIPTION_BREAKDOWN A
ON
        P.SITE_ID = A.SITE_ID
        AND P.DATE_KEY = A.EVENT_DATE
) t
```

The article states that there can't be any of the following in the view:

```
There is no GROUP BY clause in the view.
There is no DISTINCT in the view.
There is no ORDER BY, result offset, or fetch first clause in the view.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes on your solution:

```
    CASE
        WHEN SITE_ID IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(SITE_ID) OVER (
        ORDER BY EVENT_DATE ) 
        ELSE SITE_ID
    END AS SITE_ID,
```

if this is Snowflake, can be expressed as:

```
    IFF(SITE_ID IS NULL, FIRST_VALUE(SITE_ID) OVER (ORDER BY EVENT_DATE), SITE_ID) AS SITE_ID,
```

and given SQL is case insensitive (by default) you can also drop some of the shouting:

```
IFF(site_id IS NULL, FIRST_VALUE(site_id) OVER (ORDER BY event_date), site_id) AS site_id,
```

In the SELECT region of `T` you are selecting

```
   SELECT
        A.SITE_ID,
        A.COUNTRY_NAME,
        A.PRODUCT_NAME,
        P.DATE_KEY AS EVENT_DATE,
        A.ACTIVE_SUBSCRIPTIONS,
        A.ACTIVE_SUBSCRIPTIONS_CUMUL,
```

but given this is a left join, `A.SITE_ID` can be null, thus for that field it's would make more sense for that to be:

```
   SELECT
        P.SITE_ID,
        A.COUNTRY_NAME,
        A.PRODUCT_NAME,
        P.DATE_KEY AS EVENT_DATE,
        A.ACTIVE_SUBSCRIPTIONS,
        A.ACTIVE_SUBSCRIPTIONS_CUMUL,
```

and yes so much shouting..